# Kafka Streams metrics reseting when instance of application is terminated

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

We currently have two instances of the same stream application running.  Metrics are being reported correctly while both are running.  When we terminate one of the stream application the metrics on the running instance all are reset to 0. Why?  Is this expected behavior?

We are using KafkaStreams#allMetadata() to get the metric from the remote application instances and KafkaStreams#metrics() to get local metric data.  I know it is not a timing thing as number of samples is set to a large number so they are not getting reset to the data being old.

We are using 1.1.1

More Details on how we get them from remote application:
KafkaStreams#allMetadata() returns a list of StreamsMetadata which has the host and port of the remote application.  We make a rest call to that host and a rest endpoint I created.  That rest endpoint returns the result of KafkaStreams#metrics().  All of that works.  When I an application leaves the cluster the metrics all get reset to 0. I can see this also in jconsole.

Answer (score 0):

When an application leaves the cluster, the tasks will get migrated to other hosts, and hence `KafkaStreams#allMetadata()` should be refreshed to get the new end points to query metrics.